# I dont understand request flows

Tags: django

Having read a bit, I still don't understand. Can you help me see where I am going wrong?

- a view function sends out a request and gets a response
- a httprequest contains info about a currently requested url.
- httprequest objects have 2 attributes containing info submitted by
  user. GET and POST
- Use post when requesting sensitive information, use get when not.
- Post data is generally submitted from an html Form.

OK then. If I want sensitive information from a user such as their name, dob etc, I put the requested info inside a form on the html side. On the server side I gather that info by using an object 
request and its attribute POST. I then point it to the html input name I specifically want. Thus we have request.POST['Name'] this will return a string value which I give to a variable of my choosing. Thus name = request.POST['Name']. name on the server side will now hold the users entered name.

Before I continue, is there anything I have gotten wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly right.

The distinction between GET and POST, however, isn't anything to do with sensitive information. It's true that GET data is visible in the URL (after the `?`) and POST data isn't, but that doesn't make POST any more secure - it's trivial to get that data if you want to.

In fact the difference is really one of semantics. GET is used when you're just requesting particular information from the server - for instance, page 2 of a set, or a specific search query. POST is used when you're *updating* information - submitting a form to change stored data.

Apart from that, you're just about there. One thing that will probably help you is to read up on Django's [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/), which does a lot of the work in generation and validation of forms for you.

Answer (score 0):

You got one tiny bit of it wrong.

The user sends out a request, which the view function receives, then the view function sends out a response.

And HTTP objects have a lot more information included than just GET and POST variables. See [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) for more information about this.